# How to scan and connect to a bluetooth device in one fragment and read characteristics in another fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I just started learning Android development with Kotlin and I am working on an app.
I also created an Arduino device with BLE that sends the current speed of my bike.

The app I am building has one activity which will host three fragments.

1. First fragment allows the user to pick a bike and automatically
   starts the second fragment
2. Second fragment scans and connects to the Arduino
   device I mentioned earlier, **this is done in the viewModel**. 
   I am using BluetoothDevice and BluetoothGatt to scan,
   connect and read characteristics. 
    Upon successful connection, starts the third fragment
3. Third fragment is meant to enable notifications, read the characteristic and display the
   value.

#### The problem

The bluetoothGatt object is created in the second fragment and it cannot be passed as an argument to the third fragment so it cannot be used by the third fragment to enable notifications and read its characteristics.

Also, I know the device name and MAC address which I use to automatically connect.

I read about background services, broadcast receivers, etc. I am not sure which way to go

**Please tell me what is the best approach to do this so I can start learning.**

Comment: You can use the interface callback. check this tutorial https://www.journaldev.com/14207/android-passing-data-between-fragments and try to apply it on your end.

Comment: You can also add your Bluetooth related code in Activity which loads these fragments, and communicate using the interface. Try to keep only UI related code in the fragment